# Best Way To Download File Using Adobe AIR

Tags: php, actionscript-3, air, flex4

I am creating adobe AIR application, which make request to php page to take backup of website and mysql and store it on website. If I want to download that backup, what is best way? Either using FTP Socket Communication or using URLStream and FileStream. Keeping in mind that backup files will be of large size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use URLStream and FileStream. I used it to download big files many times and when implemented correctly it works great.

Comment: Ok, thanks for replying, but can you tell me how much size of files, that you downloaded?